# Run Javascript after downloading webpage Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, forms

I'm trying to write a script that writes an input and presses a button on a webpage in order to send a request.

The issue is that the input and button are within a `<script type="text/template">` tag and are not rendered.

Furthermore, I believe the website sends off the information using AJAX and not a simple form so I can't just post the data myself.

How would I run the Javascript on the webpage as if I am looking at the webpage in the browser so I can input the data and click the button? Thanks

Below is the button which is not in a form:

```
<p><button type="button" class="btn go block submit">Click Me!</button></p>
```

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting to write a Python web client? Try Googling that and see what you find.

Comment: You can absolutely send a POST request with JSON data to mimick the form being submitted

Comment: Actually I can't. The webpage is sending information using AJAX (no new webpage is opened when you click the button) and it looks like it is using socket.io. I'm looking at selenium to solve this issue.

Comment: I'm familiar with what AJAX does however it's not only possible to post JSON data without using a form it's very common. This is probbaly a better way to do what you are looking for: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using  [Selenium/Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/),
It's really simple and powerful browser automation tool.